# Is my application of chain rule on Banach spaces correct?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, banach-spaces, chain-rule

I'm reviewing my understanding on derivative on Banach spaces. Could you please verify if it looks fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Thank you so much for your help!

> Suppose that $E,F$ are Banach spaces and that $f:E \to F$ is differentiable on $E$. For $a, v \in E$, we define a map $$\begin
> {array}{l|rcl}
> g & \mathbb R
>  & \longrightarrow & F \\
>     & t & \longmapsto & f(a+tv) \end{array}$$
>
> Compute $\partial g (t)$.

---

**My understanding:**

By the definition of total derivative, we have $\partial f (x) \in \mathcal L(E,F)$, i.e. $$\begin
{array}{l|rcl}
\partial f (x) & E
 & \longrightarrow & F \\
    & y & \longmapsto & \partial f (x) (y) \end{array}$$

Here $\partial f (x) (y)$ denotes the value of the map $\partial f (x)$ when evaluated at $y$. Hence $\partial f (x) (y)$ is not the arithmetic product of $\partial f (x)$ and $y$.

Consider the map $$\begin
{array}{l|rcl}
h & \mathbb R
 & \longrightarrow & E \\
    & t & \longmapsto & a+tv \end{array}$$

It follows that $$\begin
{array}{l|rcl}
\partial h(t) & \mathbb R
 & \longrightarrow & E \\
    & l & \longmapsto & lv \end{array}$$

It follows from $g = f \circ h$ and the chain rule that $\partial g (t) = \partial f (h(t)) \circ \partial h(t)$. This means $$\begin
{array}{l|rcl}
\partial g(t) & \mathbb R
 & \longrightarrow & F \\
    & l & \longmapsto & \partial f(a+tv)(lv) \end{array}$$ and consequently $$\forall t,l \in \mathbb R:\partial g(t) (l) = \partial f(a+tv)(lv)$$

It follows from $\partial f(a+tv)$ is a linear map that $$\forall t,l \in \mathbb R:\partial g(t) (l) = \Big(\partial f(a+tv)(v)\Big) \cdot l$$

Here $\Big(\partial f(a+tv)(v)\Big) \cdot l$ denotes the arithmetic product of $\partial f(a+tv)(v)$ and $l$.

By the the definition of directional derivative, we have $$\forall t,l \in \mathbb R:\partial g(t) (l) = \Big(D_v f(a+tv)\Big) \cdot l$$

Here $\Big(D_v f(a+tv)\Big) \cdot l$ denotes the arithmetic product of $D_v f(a+tv)$ and $l$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've told us the question you're trying to solve. But it seems that you have written some map $g:\mathbb R \to F$ as a composition
$$ g = f \circ h$$
and are trying to apply chain rule. Note that the functions are related to the spaces like

$$\mathbb R \xrightarrow{h} E \xrightarrow{f} F$$
in particular, $\partial h$ has no reason to care about $F$. It should be
$$\partial h : \mathbb R\to L(\mathbb R,E)$$
or
$$ \partial h(t) : \mathbb R \to E.$$

The chain rule is then correctly applied, if I understand your yet undefined symbols correctly,  but I would advise against using the symbol $l$ for a parameter and then writing it as if its a linear map $l(\dots)$.

PS: following the discussion on Meta here: [The problem with proof verification](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29119/the-problem-with-proof-verification) I think it would be better if in the future, you posted your solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I'm sorry for not being clear enough. My question is to compute $\partial g (t)$.

Comment: Oh :(, when writting $\Big(D_v f(a+tv)\Big)l$, I meant the arithmetic product of $l$ and $D_v f(a+tv)$. Could you please elaborate on which symbols are undefined in **undefined symbols**?

Comment: Thank you so much, there is a typo as you pointed out in $$\begin
{array}{l|rcl}
\partial h(t) & \mathbb R
 & \longrightarrow & F \\
    & l & \longmapsto & lv \end{array}$$ It should be $$\begin
{array}{l|rcl}
\partial h(t) & \mathbb R
 & \longrightarrow & E \\
    & l & \longmapsto & lv \end{array}$$

Comment: @AbstractAnalysis I meant $D_v f$, I think there are two possible definitions for this (sometimes $D_v f = D_{v/\|v\|} f$ and sometimes not...) also I've never used this notation outside the context of $\mathbb R^n$ but I guess there's no reason to not just allow it

Comment: Oh, I thought the definition of $D_{v} f\left(x_{0}\right)$ is quite standard. In my textbook, $D_{v} f\left(x_{0}\right)$ is defined as $$
D_{v} f\left(x_{0}\right)=\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f\left(x_{0}+t v\right)-f\left(x_{0}\right)}{t}
$$

Comment: @AbstractAnalysis you know what, I think you're right, that is much more common. Maybe only the name is making me confused. After all, it is a **directional** derivative, so why should it depend also on the magnitude of $v$...but yes with this its OK

Comment: Thank you so much for your support :))